# How do I make my text disappear when I hover over my div?

Tags: css, html, hover

This is the only thing in the body of the HTML:

```
    <div id="box">
        <p id="text"> Enter The Disco! </p>
    </div>
```

and this is my CSS relating to the problem:

```
#box:hover{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    opacity:1;
    background-image:url("Logo.jpg");
    width:428px;
    height:208px;
    font-size:38px;
}
#text:hover{
    padding:18% 0% 0% 0%;
    color:red;
}
```

And what I want to do is make the text inside the div disappear when I hover over it how do I do this? It already spins and changes background but i just want the text to disappear after it has finished its animation.

Comment: I suggest "abracadabra"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`color` CSS attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color) and instead of making it invisible, just make it transparent, which should have the same effect:

```
#text:hover {
  /* other rules */
  color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use different way too. It is easy too like another solutions:

```
#text:hover {
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's no problem to let it disappear: use display:none, opacity:0, visibility:hidden or color:transparent; but hiding it AFTER the animation? This seems to be a bit more difficult. I don't think that this is possible without javascript:

```
<div id="box" onmouseover="spin();">
  <p id="text"> Enter The Disco! </p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var i; var rotate;

  function spin() {
    i = 180; rotate = setInterval("spinInterval()",3);
  }

  function spinInterval() {
    document.getElementById('box').style.WebkitTransform = "rotate("+ i +"deg)";
    document.getElementById('box').style.MozTransform = "rotate("+ i +"deg)";
    document.getElementById('box').style.OTransform = "rotate("+ i +"deg)";
    document.getElementById('box').style.Transform = "rotate("+ i +"deg)";
    i++;
    if(i>360) {
      document.getElementById("text").style.opacity = 0;
      clearInterval(rotate);
    }
  }
</script>
```

PS: this works for all browsers, not only on Chrome :)

Comment: It does stay hidden after the animation because im using -webkit-transition so it stays disapeared as long as im hovering over the text

Comment: But this is the only way to hide the text after the animation instead of during the animation. By the way, if you want to do it just with css, you need "transition:1s;", and then you should add "-moz-transform", "-o-transform" and "transform", or it only works in browsers based on webkit!

Comment: I know what you mean but I only want the text to disapear when I hover over the div and it works fine and ye I have added all the other transform things for the other browser just wanted to get it to run in chrome first